Import VBA enabled Template into new sheet
I have VBA enabled template sheet.
I have one module with Subs and code inside ThisWorkbook that subscribes to changes
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sh
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    ' Check if the sheet contains "Strata Plan #:" in cell A1
    If ws.Range("A1").Value = "Strata Plan #:" Then
        ' Call InvestmentAccounts if changes occur in E26:E32
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("E26:E32")) Is Nothing Then
            Call InvestmentAccounts(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call S110Notes if changes occur in E34 or E45
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("E34, E45")) Is Nothing Then
            Call S110Notes(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call Laundry if changes occur in E35
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("E35")) Is Nothing Then
            Call Laundry(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call ManagementFees if changes occur in E26, E35, or E37
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("E26, E35, E37")) Is Nothing Then
            Call ManagementFees(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call WithholdingTax if changes occur in H25
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("H25")) Is Nothing Then
            Call WithholdingTax(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call OtherDeductions if changes occur in H25, E35, or E37
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("H25, E35, E37")) Is Nothing Then
            Call OtherDeductions(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call OwnerOccupier if changes occur in E35
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("E35")) Is Nothing Then
            Call OwnerOccupier(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call JunBal if changes occur in H25 or H34
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("H25, H34")) Is Nothing Then
            Call JunBal(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call LevyIncome if changes occur in H25, E35, or E37
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("H25, E35, E37")) Is Nothing Then
            Call LevyIncome(ws)
        End If
        
        ' Call WorkpapersArea if changes occur in E26, E35, E37, E65, or E66
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("E26, E35, E37, E65, E66")) Is Nothing Then
            Call WorkpapersArea(ws)
        End If
    End If

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ws.Calculate ' Force a recalculation of the worksheet
    ws.Activate ' Reactivate the sheet to force a redraw
End Sub



And it works great. When I open it as new -> template.
All of the macros are imported.
The problem is when I go NewSheet -> right click -> insert -> [Choose Template] the macros are not copied.
How can I copy the macros together with new sheet?

If you want to apply the change event code for all sheets in the workbook, pls use Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range). It works for all existing sheets and new added sheets.

When creating a new sheet based on the template only the worksheets module (code) is transferred not the workbooks module of the template.

I need to subscribe to events, can that be done from worksheet module?

The solution was to create an extension.
When extension is installed, it adds right click context menu.
When uninstalled, it removes it.
Then, the code works like this when you right click and select template

merge ThisWorkbook code from template to the main code
copy all VBA modules from the template

